# Getting info from .properties file Java

Tags: java

I have to write a code which translates numbers into words and it's supposed to be universal for different languages. For this purpose I have a .properties file which looks something like this.

```
40=forty

50=fifty

80=eighty

teen=teen

tens-suffix=ty

tens-after-delimiter=-
```

This is my code so far:

```
 public String numberInWords(Integer number) {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    FileInputStream is = null;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(filePath);

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                is, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

        properties.load(reader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exceptions
    } finally {
        close(is);
    }
```

I know that I can get number values like this:

```
properties.getProperty(String.valueOf(number));
```

But how am I supposed to add the value "teen" to the result string?
I tried something along the lines like the last line of code but my IDE says it cannot resolve the symbol.

Thanks

Edit:

This was an example property file. I am well aware that adding "teen" won't work with other languages. In my property files I already have exceptions like 11 - eleven, 12 - twelve and so on. For example in my estonian property file I have a line:

teen=teist,

this will work on all estonian numbers. I need to find a way to add the teen value to a string. If an input is estonian, it will use the estonian property file and so on. This is determined in my other method.

I am trying to find a method that allows me to get the value teen="something" from a property file so I can add this to the string. Every property file is separate and has exceptions in them.

This line won't work, because it cannot resolve symbol teen:

properties.getProperty(String.valueOf(teen));

I am looking for a solution for this exact probleem

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to do. What exactly do you want to do with that value ```teen```?

Comment: You need to write code that looks at the input number and decides if you even need the "teen" part (which in english is only the case for 13-19) and then append these strings together. This is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with bundle resources. That allows you to read the same property from different property files based on your current locale. Read this article: [Backing a ResourceBundle with Properties Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. I don't think you can create a universal translator like that because all languages treat their numbers differently. While the english language will append `teen` to numbers between 13 and 19, other languages don't do it like that. Also simply appending `teen` won't even work for English.

Append `teen` to `three` will be `threeteen` and not `thirteen`.